# Saving Output of Algorithm using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm new to PyQGIS and trying to save the output of the processing tool 'create points layer from table'. I just need to save it as a shapefile. My code is below which seems to be functioning so far. Using QGIS v3.4.

```
params = { 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/xxx/WeeklyContacts-2019-07-15.csv', 'MFIELD' : None, 'OUTPUT' : 'memory:', 'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:27700'), 'XFIELD' : 'Easting', 'YFIELD' : 'Northing', 'ZFIELD' : None }
processing.run("qgis:createpointslayerfromtable", params)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 'OUTPUT' parameter is 'memory:'. That means once the processing finishes, you will get a temporary memory layer. Change it to a shapefile and a shapefile will be saved to the disk.

```
params = { 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/xxx/WeeklyContacts-2019-07-15.csv', 'MFIELD' : None, 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/xxx/WeeklyContacts-2019-07-15.shp', 'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:27700'), 'XFIELD' : 'Easting', 'YFIELD' : 'Northing', 'ZFIELD' : None }
processing.run("qgis:createpointslayerfromtable", params)
```